# How to define "ENUM" type and put values in a loopback model itself?

Tags: loopbackjs

How to define "ENUM" type and put values in a model itself? If thats not possible, then in the documentation, its mentioned to use enum like this 
https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/MySQL-connector.html#enum
But where should I put this code as per best practice ?

Answer (score 1):

You could add custom validation to your model, so it would check if the value you're passing is correct. You can find a more elaborated answer here:

[Can I define a custom validation with options for Loopback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32631763/can-i-define-a-custom-validation-with-options-for-loopback)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this way with MYSQL Connector.

```
"properties": {
    "name": {
      "type": "string",
      "mysql": {
        "columnName": "name",
        "dataType": "ENUM('Daily', 'Week Days','Weekends','Monthly','Custom')",
        "default": "Week Days"
      }
    }
}
```

`

Answer (score 1):

Use [ENUM property](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/Model.html#enum-property) in JSON Schema

```
@property({
  type: 'string',
  required: true,
  jsonSchema: {
    enum: ['Daily', 'Week Days','Weekends','Monthly','Custom'],
  },
})
```